# Why does typing variable length Tuple require ellipses but List does not?

Tags: python, typing

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Tuple):

> To specify a variable-length tuple of homogeneous type, use literal ellipsis, e.g. Tuple[int, ...]. A plain Tuple is equivalent to Tuple[Any, ...], and in turn to tuple.

So therefore, the annotation `Tuple[int]` specifies a tuple containing a single integer; yet `List[int]` implies variable length.

Why must `...` be used with `Tuple[int, ...]` and not with `List[int]` if both can be homeo/hetero-geneous?

Comment: Because lists are mutable and are not expected to have a fixed size at any given point. If you have a list of fixed size, you should (conceptually) be using a tuple or a queue.

Comment: @jfaccioni Ah, well I looked at it from the point of "explicit rather than implicit". Your comment makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A tuple is typically used for a small heterogenous set of values of fixed size. Therefore the type hint takes individual arguments denoting the type of each value, e.g. `Tuple[str, int, list]`. A homogeneous tuple is really a special case, and the `...` notation is a shorthand for it.

A list is typically a homogenous sequence of undefined length. Hence its type hint only takes one argument.